# ORM Techniques or conceptual framework to one table, one class?

Tags: orm, mapping, entity, design-patterns

I wanna know if there exists conceptual framework or documented techniques to study how to map entities classes to database tables??

Before I was using JPA (Java Persistance API) to map one table -> one entity class, this is: each table's row represented by one object class. Is it the most common/correct way? Has these patterns specific names?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One table to one class is called the "**Active Record**" pattern.  One alternative pattern people use is the **Repository** pattern.  **DDD** (Domain Driven Design) has the concept of Aggregate Roots which also plays in this space.  You should be able to do some reading on that terminology.  I am personally not in love with any of those patterns, they all have pros and cons.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I coded a Persistence<T> library because I was not happy with LAZY/EAGER fetch types (JPA), now I have to write some conceptual framework about my intuitive develop, you put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there is no recipe, formula or pattern for the ideal class to table relationship. The key point to mapping is that it acts as an adapter layer, isolating the table structure from the entity structure.
If you are designing your application and tables at the same time, I think you should design your tables to minimise round trips, getting as much data to hydrate your entities as possible. Then let your mapper(s) build the entities and any appropriate associations. This might lead you to denormalise your table structure a little more than you might normally.